# Add specify Subnet for EC2 in another module - AWS Terraform -

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I'm Terraform newbie.
I have vpc module and ec2 module.

- VPC module creates 3 public subnets.
- Ec2 module creates 2 instances.

-> So I want that public subnet 1 used by the 1st instance, public subnet 3 used by the 2nd instance. I used output variables, but I don't know how to work with output. Pls, help me

The provider is AWS

**VPC module**

```
#/module/vpc/main.tf
resource "aws_subnet" "pub_subnet" {
    count = var.create_vpc && length(var.public_subnet) > 0 ? length(var.public_subnet) : 0
    vpc_id = local.vpc_id
    availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)
    cidr_block = element(var.public_subnet, count.index)
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true
    # network_acls = aws_network_acl.nacls
    tags = merge ({
        Name = format("Pub_subnet %s", element(var.public_subnet, count.index))
    },
    var.tags
    )
}
```

```
#module/vpc/output
output "public_subnet_id" {
    value = aws_subnet.pub_subnet[0].id
}
```

**EC2 Module**

```
#/module/ec2/variables
variable "ec2_instance" {
    type = map(object({
        ec2_name = string
        ec2_ami = string
        ec2_instance_type = string
        ec2_subnet_id = string
        ec2_associate_public_ip_address = string
        ec2_key_name = string
        ec2_security_groups = list(string)
        ec2_user_data = string
        root_block_device_volume_type = string
        root_block_device_volume_size = number
        root_block_device_iops = number
        root_block_device_throughput = number
    }))
}
```

```
#/module/vpc/main.tf
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
      for_each = var.ec2_instance
      ami           = each.value.ec2_ami
      instance_type = each.value.ec2_instance_type
      subnet_id = each.value.ec2_subnet_id
      associate_public_ip_address = each.value.ec2_associate_public_ip_address
      key_name = each.value.ec2_key_name
      security_groups = each.value.ec2_security_groups
      user_data = each.value.ec2_user_data
      root_block_device {
      volume_type = each.value.root_block_device_volume_type
      volume_size = each.value.root_block_device_volume_size
      iops = each.value.root_block_device_iops
      throughput = each.value.root_block_device_throughput
  }
      tags = merge ({
        Name = format("%s", each.value.ec2_name)
    },
    var.tags
    )
}
```

**Root module**

```
#/main.tf
module "vpc" {
source = "../../modules/ec2"
public_subnet = [ "13.9.1.0/24", "13.9.2.0/24", "13.9.7.0/24" ]
}
module "ec2"{
    source = "../../modules/ec2"
    ec2_instance = {
      "bastion_pub_sub_1" = {
        ec2_name = "bastion_pub_sub_1"
        ec2_ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_20_04.id
        ec2_associate_public_ip_address = true
        ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
        ec2_key_name = #secret
        ec2_subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnet_id
        ec2_user_data = "value"
        root_block_device_iops = 3000
        root_block_device_throughput = 125
        root_block_device_volume_size = 8
        root_block_device_volume_type = "gp3"
      },
    source = "../../qa_modules/ec2"
    ec2_instance = {
      "bastion_pub_sub_2" = {
        ec2_name = "bastion_pub_sub_2"
        ec2_ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_20_04.id
        ec2_associate_public_ip_address = true
        ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
        ec2_key_name = #secret
        ec2_subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnet_id
        ec2_user_data = "value"
        root_block_device_iops = 3000
        root_block_device_throughput = 125
        root_block_device_volume_size = 8
        root_block_device_volume_type = "gp3"
      }
}
```

So, at **ec2_subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnet_id**, how can i add the subnet "13.9.1.0/24" for instance "bastion_pub_sub_1", subnet "13.9.7.0/24" for instance "bastion_pub_sub_2"

Comment: You have to show your code, and explain what's wrong with it, provide any errors, and describe exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Marcin sry, i have update. Help me pls

Comment: How many subnets do you have? What is `var.public_subnet`?

Comment: @Marcin updated subnet. i have 3 subnet [ "13.9.1.0/24", "13.9.2.0/24", "13.9.7.0/24" ]. and 2 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outputs should be:

```
output "public_subnet_id" {
    value = aws_subnet.pub_subnet[*].id
}
```

then:

```
module "ec2"{
    source = "../../modules/ec2"
    ec2_instance = {
      "bastion_pub_sub_1" = {
        ec2_name = "bastion_pub_sub_1"
        ec2_ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_20_04.id
        ec2_associate_public_ip_address = true
        ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
        ec2_key_name = #secret
        ec2_subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnet_id[0]
        ec2_user_data = "value"
        root_block_device_iops = 3000
        root_block_device_throughput = 125
        root_block_device_volume_size = 8
        root_block_device_volume_type = "gp3"
      },
    source = "../../qa_modules/ec2"
    ec2_instance = {
      "bastion_pub_sub_2" = {
        ec2_name = "bastion_pub_sub_2"
        ec2_ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_20_04.id
        ec2_associate_public_ip_address = true
        ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
        ec2_key_name = #secret
        ec2_subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnet_id[2]
        ec2_user_data = "value"
        root_block_device_iops = 3000
        root_block_device_throughput = 125
        root_block_device_volume_size = 8
        root_block_device_volume_type = "gp3"
      }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. let me try it

Comment: nice!!! thank you for your help, I solved it. it took me 1 day for solving. thank god you are here

Comment: @LamboOP No problem. Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated if it helped.

Comment: I voted this answer is useful but I'm a new member of StackOverflow :(

Comment: @LamboOP To accept have to press a tick symbol as shown here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979